# Apache module development, correct way to store variables of request

Tags: c, apache, apache-modules

At the moment I store them in global. Is that the correct way ? I want the variable to stay with the current request and goes away after the request is finished.

For example:

```
int data1;
int data2;

apr_status_t my_input_filter (ap_filter_t *f, apr_bucket_brigade *bb,
    ap_input_mode_t mode, apr_read_type_e block, apr_off_t readbytes) {
    if (somecond1) data1 = xyz;
    if (somecond2 & data1 == xya) data2 = abc;

    if (somecond3 && data2 == abc) dosomething();
}
```

Note that the 3 cond may not happen in one go while filtering, they may appear at different moment, but with the same request.

Answer (score 0):

If your module runs with either the event or the multithreaded package, storing in a global variable is a bad bad bad idea.

Apache provides a notes dictionary in the request structure.  Use it for storing your private data.

Comment: For input_filter, my f->r is always NULL I guess I can't use the note

Comment: Trick #2: create your own hash table indexed by connection that stores your data.  Add a cleanup hook to the connection->pool to remove the hash entry when the connection dies.